# Whats wrong with this line of PHP code?

Tags: php, runtime-error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Pre' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in your code on line 719

```
719: if (get_the_author_meta('Pre-Rolls') != '0') { echo get_the_author_meta('Pre-Rolls'); }
```

I dont see where I'm missing a , or ;?

Does it not like the "-" in Pre-Rolls? Is that the problem?

Comment: You’re probably missing a `'` somewhere before that line.

Comment: as @Gumbo said this line looks pretty clean, it is surely something on the line before it

Comment: Is the `719:` supposed to be there?

Comment: `; if (get_the_author_meta('Pre-Rolls') != '0') { echo get_the_author_meta('Pre-Rolls'); }` would probably solve it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issue with code that comes before this line. Unexpected 'Pre' suggests that you haven't closed a string (missing single quote).

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I used a " instead of ' to close a line.